# how do I change the name that appears in emails I send from my app?

Tags: email, google-apps

I have a domain name I am sending emails from via my rails app on heroku. The email is setup via google apps. Every time I send an email from my app, the name that appears (at least in my gmail account) on the left side is my name. however, I've tried to change how this appears in a bunch of places with no luck. How do I make it say the name of my company rather than my personal name?

PS. the email address I am sending from is myname@mycompany.com.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The sender will be the user id used to authenticate to the Google smtp server.